# Is React context supposed to always be a singleton, or is there another way?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Every example I've seen of `React` context is like [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html):

```
theme-context.js

// Make sure the shape of the default value passed to
// createContext matches the shape that the consumers expect!
export const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
  theme: themes.dark,
  toggleTheme: () => {},
});
```

Where you're having a file contain an instance of the context. Then you pass it into the component using `useContext(ThemeContext)`.

My question is, if you're doing this and it's *always* a singleton, why don't you simply just import the stuff in the context directly from the singleton so to speak. Basically I'm wondering if there is ever a time where you create more than one instance of your context, such as perhaps for testing you create a new one per test, something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this question myself.
(If I understand the question correctly)

And I think you may misunderstand that the `useContext` is singleton instance, Which I did but I just try it out and it's allow me to use multiple instances of the same context.

So basically `const ContextA = createContext({})` is for create a type reference not a data instance.

And using `ContextA.Provider` (the provider) is to an actual data instance.
And you can use as many provider you want.

The reason we need singleton context (createContext) is because js doesn't have type, So we can't query any target provider using a type

Answer (score -3):

First of all, the value in `React.createContext({'light'})` is default. 
It is mostly used for debug or just skip it, and leave it empty `React.createContext()`.
Example of usage: 
You have a data in your Context.Provider, but you are not sure, if you passed it right to your `Product.Consumer`, so if the default value pops out, you know that you did something wrong.

In documention such technique is used to pass simple data, like singletone `React.createContext({'theme:themes.dark'})`.

In most cases, you will use `Context.Provider` and `Context.Consumer`, or even pass through `this.context`.

Documentation strictly explained every details, try search for `Context.Provider, Class.contextType, Context.Consumer` in documentation.