# Difference between React Context and JS singleton

Tags: reactjs

[React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) is a way to make an object available in all components of my React tree without having to thread the object through the props of intermediary components.  [ES6 modules also offer a simple way](https://medium.com/@dmnsgn/singleton-pattern-in-es6-d2d021d150ae) to make a singleton global object.

Context is a little more cumbersome because I have to add an element to the render tree for every new thing I want to put in the "global scope".  So what's the advantage of using Context over a singleton global object?

Comment: Possible duplicate please read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57123255/is-react-context-supposed-to-always-be-a-singleton-or-is-there-another-way

Comment: How would you trigger React to rerender when your module singleton values change?

Comment: I guess that kind of answers my question.  I was thinking about the case where it doesn't change after the initial render (or the context just holds a function that does something else).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer I settled with, as alluded to by [azium's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58663145/difference-between-react-context-and-js-singleton#comment103630311_58663145):

Context provides more than just a global variable because it can depend on props or state which might change.  On change of the context's dependencies, the context would update and anything that's dependent on the context would rerender.

Answer (score 1):

Actually context does not update your components by itself. Context only updates your components if its using state or some kind of observable.

To answer your question. You could use a singleton with an observer pattern like [mobx](https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html#using-external-state-in-observer-components)